# Cannot have less than infinitely many solutions but more than one for a particular $b$ in $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra

$$Ax=b$$

It is not possible to have more than one but less than infinitely many solutions for a particular $b$; if both $x$ and $y$ are solutions then:

$$z=\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$$

is also a solution for any real $\alpha$.

---

Can anyone explain this? How does the right side simplify to $z$? And intuitively, why is the $(1-\alpha)$ needed as it seems arbitrary to me? It's not like an inverse or anything.

Comment: 1) The RHS doesn't "simplify to $z$".  The RHS is the thing that we're naming $z$.  2) Try plugging that $z$ in to see why it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you have one solution to $ Ax = b $, say, $ v $, then adding any solution of $ Ax = 0 $ to that vector produces another solution. Since the solutions of $ Ax = 0 $ form a vector space, the vector space is either trivial (zero dimensional) or has infinitely many elements (assuming that the base field is infinite, such as $ \mathbb{R} $ or $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: That makes sense and I see that it works out, but I'd be interested to know how would one derive the (parametric?) equation he/she mentions?

Comment: There is no derivation, just plug the expression into the equation, and you see that it is another solution.

Comment: I meant in the sense that how do you know before that $z=\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$ works aside from knowing after the fact being explained to you.

Comment: The idea is that you want the coefficients to sum to 1, and parametrizing them this way is the most natural way of ensuring that.

Answer (score 2):

Say $W = \{x \in V \mid Ax=b\}$ is the set of all solutions of your equation.

Let $x, y \in W$ be two different solutions for the given equation, i.e. $Ax = b,~ Ay = b,~ x \neq 0$. Now choose an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the vector $\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y$, let's call it $z$.

Then $Az = \alpha Ax+(1-\alpha)Ay = \alpha b + (1-\alpha) b = b$,
so $z$ is also a solution of the given equation, it follows $z \in W$.

Now let's check that changing $\alpha$ will also change $z$: We can rewrite $z$ as $y + \alpha(x-y)$, and since $x \neq y$, we have $x - y \neq 0.$ Thus changing $\alpha$ will indeed give us a different $z$.

This means that for any real $\alpha$ there is a different solution to the equation, hence there are infinitely many.

We can formally write this as an injective function $f : \mathbb{R} \to W$ with $f(\alpha) = y + \alpha(x-y)$. Since $f$ is injective, $W$ must contain at least as many elements as $\mathbb{R}$, so infinitely many.

Answer (score 1):

Important to note that this has an implicit assumption that the underlying fields is infinite.

Simply, if $x_0$ and $x_1$ are both distinct solutions to $Ax = b$ then:
$$\frac{1}{2}x_0 + \frac{1}{2}x_1$$
Must also be a solution (and distinct) since:
$$A(\frac{1}{2}x_0 + \frac{1}{2}x_1) = \frac{1}{2}Ax_0 + \frac{1}{2}Ax_1 = b$$
From this we can derive infinitely many solutions by always using the linearity of $A$ and $\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x_0$ is a solution, i.e., $Ax_0=b.$

Now let $x$ be another solution in $S(A,b)$. This gives $A(x-x_0)=Ax-Ax_0=b-b=0.$ Thus $(x-x_0)\in S(A,0).$ We can then write $x=x_0+(x-x_0) \in \{x_0\}+S(A,0).$ So $S(A,b) \subset \{x_0\}+S(A,0).$

Next suppose that $y\in S(A,0).$ Now $A(y+x_0)=Ay+Ax_0=b+0=b.$ So $(y+x_0)\in S(A,b).$ Thus $\{x_0\} + S(A,0) \subset S(A,b).$

Putting these together gives $S(A,b)=\{x_0\}+S(A,0).$

So adding any other solution in $S(A,0)$ gives you another solution.